# How to structure a node to publish a topic using classes?

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a node but I have some doubts of how to structure it if I am using classes. Right now I have written two methods. The first one is:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
class node_class
{
public:
    node_class();
private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    ros::Publisher pub_;
    std_msgs::String msg;
    ros::Rate loop_rate;
};
node_class::node_class():
    pub_(nh_.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 10)),
    loop_rate(1)
{
    msg.data = "hello world";
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        pub_.publish(msg);
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "node_class");
    node_class this_node;
    while(ros::ok())
        ros::spinOnce();
    return 0;
}
```

In this one the loop is done inside the constructor, but I have my doubts about it. Also the `ros::ok()` is checked twice. And the second method is:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
class node_class
{
public:
    node_class();
    void loop_function();
private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    ros::Publisher pub_;
    std_msgs::String msg;
    ros::Rate loop_rate;
};
node_class::node_class():
    pub_(nh_.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 10)),
    loop_rate(1)
{
    msg.data = "hello world";
}
void node_class::loop_function()
{
    pub_.publish(msg);
    loop_rate.sleep();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "node_class");
    node_class this_node;
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        this_node.loop_function();
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am using a `loop_function` from the class to be executed in the `main while loop`. Both methods work but, are there other methods or best practices to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188909/how-to-structure-a-node-to-publish-a-topic-using-classes?/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Definitely the second one!

In the first one your doing an infinite loop inside a constructor, which is in my eyes really bad.

> Also the `ros::ok()` is checked twice.

No it isn't. The  `ros::ok()` call in the `main` method is being called exactly one time, namely when you hit Ctrl + C and your infinite loop in the constructor exits.

For the future have a look at the `ros::spin()` method also.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2